# Html список

Tags: html

Я создал список, в css прописал float:left; а расстояние между словами ни как не получается изменить. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как реализовать подобное?

```
<ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>PRODUCTS</li>
    <li>F.A.Q</li>
    <li>COMPANY</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @aaa, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/LMHbS/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>HOME</li>
    <li>PRODUCTS</li>
    <li>F.A.Q</li>
    <li>COMPANY</li>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>CONTACT</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/P7QYs/

HTML:

```
<ul> <li>HOME</li> <li>PRODUCTS</li> <li>F.A.Q</li> <li>COMPANY</li> <li>ABOUT</li> <li>CONTACT</li> </ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```